# Pairs of Binary Strings with a Given number of 1 Overlapping

Tags: combinatorics

I'm facing the following problem, and I would like to know whether there is already a solution in the literature.
Suppose I have two binary strings of equal length.
Fix $n_1$, the number of 1 that must appear in both of the string and a $k$, the number of of 1 that can appear in the same position in the two strings.
How many possible ways are there to set the bits in the first and second string such that there are exactly $n_1$ 1 and exactly $k$ of them are in the same position?
I don't know whether this is clear, but I hope this will be after the following example.

Set the length of the two strings $n$ to 2, the of 1 $n_1$ to 1 and the number of overlapping 1 ($k$) to 0.
With the string 0000 I indicate that 0 and 0 are chosen for the first string and 0 and 0 for the second.
The possible solutions are: 0001,0010,0100,1000. So we have 4. If $n_1=2$, we have: 0011,0110,1001,1100. So we have 4. Another one: if $k=1$ and $n_1 = 2$, we have: 0101, 1010. Is there a general formula to get this number given $n$, $n_1$, and $k$?

Comment: You want to choose $k$ positions from $2n$ where the ones will be in the same position, then $n_1-k$ from the remaining $n-k$ positions in the first string, then $n_1-k$ from the remaining $n-n_1$ positions in the second string.

Comment: If I've correctly understood, $\binom{2n}{k} \cdot \binom{n-k}{n_1-k} \cdot \binom{n-n_1}{n_1-k}$ does not seems to work, since, if, n = 2, k = 0, and $n_1$ = 1, the equations yields 2 while there are 4 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can first fix the position of $k$ ones that will overlap.
$$\text{Number of ways to choose k overlapping ones} = C^{n}_{k}$$

Now you have to find the positions of leftover $(n1-k)$ ones.
$$\text{Number of positions left} = n-k $$

$$\text{Number of ways to choose (n1-k) non-overlapping ones} = 2^{n1-k}\cdot C^{n-k}_{n1-k}$$

You multiply it by $2^{n1-k}$ because you have choice if you want to place the one in string $s1$ or $s2$.

$$ans = 2^{n1-k}\cdot C^{n-k}_{n1-k}.\cdot C^{n}_{k}$$

Comment: This does not seem to work since if n = 2, k = 1, and $n_1$=2, with the formula I get 4 while there are only 2 solutions: 1010 and 0101